# How to change a random turtle's color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, turtle-graphics

I need to choose a person randomly from a list then infect them with the virus (changing their turtle color to red) when I press 'x'.  Then I have to count how many people are infected.

Currently, my code does not change any turtle's color and I also don't know how to count how many red turtle are there.

```
#used to infect 
class Virus:
    def __init__(self, colour, duration):
        self.colour = colour
        self.duration = duration
class Person:
    def __init__(self, world_size):
        self.world_size = world_size
        self.radius = 7
        self.location = turtle.position()
        self.destination = self._get_random_location()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(self.location)
        turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(self.destination))
        self.heading = turtle.heading()

    #random locations are used to assign a destination for the person
    #the possible locations should not be closer than 1 radius to the edge of the world 
    def _get_random_location(self):
        x = random.randint( - 349, 349 )
        y = random.randint( - 249, 249 )
        return (x, y)


    #draw a person using a dot.  Use colour if implementing Viruses 
    def draw(self):
        x, y = self.location
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(x, y - self.radius)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.begin_fill()
        self.x = turtle.circle(self.radius)
        turtle.end_fill()

#infect a person with the given virus
    def infect(self, virus):
        v_colour = virus.colour
        turtle.colormode("v_colour")
class World:
    def __init__(self, width, height, n):
        self.size = (width, height)
        self.hours = 0
        self.people = []
        self.infected = 0
        for i in range(n):
            self.add_person()


    #add a person to the list
    def add_person(self):
        person = Person(1)
        self.people.append(person)


    #choose a random person to infect and infect with a Virus when press 'x'
    def infect_person(self):
        random_ppl = random.choice(self.people)
        v = Virus("red", 100)
        random_ppl.infect(v)

    #remove all infections from all people when press'c'
    def cure_all(self):
        turtle.colormode('black')
        self.infected = 0

def draw(self):
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.setheading(0)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(-350, -250)
        turtle.pendown()

        for i in range(2):
            turtle.forward(500)
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(700)
            turtle.right(90)

        for item in self.people:
            item.draw()

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(-350, 250)
        turtle.write(f'Hours: {self.hours}', move=False, align='left')
        self.count_infected()
        turtle.setposition(0, 250)
        turtle.write(f'Infected: {self.infected}', move=False, align='left')
        turtle.update()



    #Count the number of infected people
    def count_infected(self):
        p = Person(1)
        p.draw()
        dot = p.x
        color = dot.color()
        Color = color[0]
        if Color is 'red':
            self.infected += 1

#code for the keys
class GraphicalWorld:
    """ Handles the user interface for the simulation

    space - starts and stops the simulation
    'z' - resets the application to the initial state
    'x' - infects a random person
    'c' - cures all the people
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.WIDTH = 800
        self.HEIGHT = 600
        self.TITLE = 'COMPSCI 130 Project One'
        self.MARGIN = 50 #gap around each side
        self.PEOPLE = 200 #number of people in the simulation
        self.framework = AnimationFramework(self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT, self.TITLE)

        self.framework.add_key_action(self.setup, 'z') 
        self.framework.add_key_action(self.infect, 'x')
        self.framework.add_key_action(self.cure, 'c')
        self.framework.add_key_action(self.toggle_simulation, ' ') 
        self.framework.add_tick_action(self.next_turn)

        self.world = None

    def setup(self):
        """ Reset the simulation to the initial state """
        print('resetting the world')        
        self.framework.stop_simulation()
        self.world = World(self.WIDTH - self.MARGIN * 2, self.HEIGHT - self.MARGIN * 2, self.PEOPLE)
        self.world.draw()

    def infect(self):
        """ Infect a person, and update the drawing """
        print('infecting a person')
        self.world.infect_person()
        self.world.draw()

    def cure(self):
        """ Remove infections from all the people """
        print('cured all people')
        self.world.cure_all()
        self.world.draw()
```

The homework calls `World.infected_people()` first so I don't know how to pass the random people to `Person.infect()` then change the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a number of issues but since you didn't include your entire code, I can only give you some ideas of how to proceed:

Remember from my last answer that the solitary turtle is *shared*, so setting the turtle's color to the virus color is not sufficient.  You need to store the virus information with the *Person* and use that information when it comes time to draw the person.  I.e.:

```
# to Person.__init__ add the property
self.virus = None
```

Make your `Person.infect()` function simply:

```
def infect(self, virus):
    self.virus = virus
```

Note that the code you had: `turtle.colormode("v_colour")` is completely wrong as `colormode()` is the wrong method and `v_colour` shouldn't be in quotes.  But we don't need that anyway.  Now in your `Person.draw()` method add the following just before `turtle.begin_fill()`:

```
if self.virus is not None:
    turtle.color(self.virus.colour)
else:
    turtle.color("black")
```

When you type 'x', you should start seeing individuals turn red.

> I also don't know how to count how many red turtle are there.

Don't count red turtles!  (Your current `count_infected()` is completely wrong -- you shouldn't be creating new people nor drawing anything.)

You could loop over `self.people` looking for people who have a `self.virus` property that isn't `None`.  But `World` has a `self.infected` property that you should increment when `infect_person()` is called.  However, since you pick a person at random, this won't work as-is since you might increment the counter twice for the same person.  You need to change `infect_person()` to keep grabbing a random person *until* it finds one that isn't already infected.  Whether this makes sense depends on the rules of the assignment.

Your `World.cure_all()` function needs to be rewritten to loop over `self.people` calling `cure()` on each person.  The `Person.cure()` method should set the `self.virus` property back to `None`.

Comment: for the World.cure_all(), I call person.cure() on each person and set the self.virus = None but the turtle color didn't change back.

Comment: @Victoriavv, the color is set in the `Person.draw()` method based on whether the `self.virus` property is `None` or not, so it has to change back.  All I can say is recheck your code.